o.s.boot.SpringApplication , Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
My app is a simple spring-batch application which is introduced in https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing by some changes
but I find the following error when I compile it:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.755+03:30 ERROR 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: null

in application.yml file:
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  application:
    name: TestLoadData
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 60000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
  task:
    scheduling:
      pool:
        size: 3
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB




trx:
  minutes: 1


#profiles

---
#development
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.253.98:1521/xe
    username: dev_user
    password: d3vl0pm3ntD13
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10

  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
      show-sql: true

  batch:
    job:
      enabled: true
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always

======================================================================

and in console I find the following:
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64381', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)

2024-04-06T15:13:18.440+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] c.e.t.TestLoadDataApplication            : Starting TestLoadDataApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 18348 (D:\projects\TestLoadData\target\classes started by MALIHEH in D:\projects\TestLoadData)
2024-04-06T15:13:18.456+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] c.e.t.TestLoadDataApplication            : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-04-06T15:13:18.791+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-06T15:13:18.807+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.140+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.156+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.156+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$PooledDataSourceConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$PooledDataSourceConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.156+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jdbcConnectionDetails' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.188+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSource' of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.203+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'batchConfiguration' of type [com.example.testloaddata.BatchConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.203+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionManager' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.203+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.batch-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.203+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.346+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8081 (http)
2024-04-06T15:13:19.346+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-06T15:13:19.346+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2024-04-06T15:13:19.394+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-06T15:13:19.394+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 907 ms
2024-04-06T15:13:19.472+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-04-06T15:13:19.503+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
2024-04-06T15:13:19.535+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-04-06T15:13:19.661+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-04-06T15:13:19.676+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-06T15:13:19.676+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] c.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource    : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.739+03:30  WARN 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: null
2024-04-06T15:13:19.739+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-04-06T15:13:19.739+03:30  INFO 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-06T15:13:19.755+03:30 ERROR 18348 --- [TestLoadData] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.example.testloaddata.TestLoadDataApplication.main(TestLoadDataApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.<init>(NSProtocol.java:249) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.<init>(NSProtocolNIO.java:147) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:895) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1126) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:104) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:825) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:651) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:424) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 11
[A-z0-9,_]{۸}
           ^
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2204) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3488) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2390) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2245) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1945) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1576) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1101) ~[na:na]
    at oracle.net.ns.SessionAtts.<clinit>(SessionAtts.java:148) ~[ojdbc8-23.3.0.23.09.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
    ... 53 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64381', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1


It is unclear on what is going wrong based on the provided data. However, I'll try to help.
It seems that something either on driver side or DB side is miscofigured.
JVM throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to establish a connection to Oracle DB. This error indicates that the static initializer completed with an exception (I mean the static initializer of an internal oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol class).
The actual cause of ExceptionInInitializerError is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException. It tries to parse a regexp : [A-z0-9,_]{۸}, and no doubt it fails. The '۸' inside the curly braces (the quantifier in regexp) is not allowed, since it is not an integer. The quantifier expects and integer ({4} for instance) to represent the amount of previous token to be repeated on.
So, I do not fully view your driver configuration or Oracle configuration. I hope at least this will guide you to find an appropriate answer.

I really appreciate for your comment.  I couldn't find my wrong pattern yet. After debug, I found my error occurs in SpringApplication.class, applicationContext.refresh() in method   protected void refresh(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
applicationContext.refresh();
}
